# Angular 5 - Make 2 GET request in synchron order, then show data in DataTable

Tags: angular

Angular 5:
In one Component I would store data in 2 arrays, which then is displayed in a DataTable.

But how the data is gotten needs some strict order:

1. GET request on a REST controller, the data coming from it shall be stored in the first array.
2. GET request on a REST controller using the data from the first array from step 1., the data coming from it shall be stored in the second array.
3. The data from 1. and 2. shall be displayed in a DataTable, some columns hold data from the objects from first array, some columns hold data from the object from the second array.

How to achieve this?
First 1. must be executed, if done, then the step 2. must be executed. If step 2. is done, then the data from both arrays shall be displayed in the DataTable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple way to do what you are asking for.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('url1').subscribe(data1 => {

     // process data1 and make call for second type of data

     this.http.get('url2').subscribe(data2 => {
       // process data2
      });

   });
  }
}
```

Comment: The question indicates the data emitted from the 1st observable/call will be used to execute the 2nd call. `forkJoin` wouldn't allow to await the results of 1st call to be used in the 2nd call, but that being said it is still unclear what the exact ask/flow really needs to be.

Comment: The flow is as described: First getting data with Step1 (GET on REST service), store the data in first array. After Step1 is finished, execute getting data with Step2 (GET on REST service, using the data from the first array from Step1 as query parameters), store the data in second array. Finally, after Step2 is finished, display data from both arrays in a DataTable, some columns are from the Objects (some of its properties) from first array, some columns are from the Objects (some of its properties) from second array. That means Step1 and Step2 cannot be executed in parallel.

Comment: @neblaz look at the code, it is not parallel execution. it serial execution.

Comment: @Md Ayub Ali Sarker It was mentioned `forkJoin`, which would be a paralle execution? Also, could you please remove unnecessary code from the snippet (ex. combineResult, forkJoin)?

Comment: I have to mark Sarker solution as helpful, because I couldn't test Staroselsky so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve executing these calls in a specific order using the [switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) RxJS operator with a result selector. `switchMap` ensures the previous observable has completed prior to beginning the next one. The result selector allows you create a data structure with values from results of both the 1st and 2nd calls. Additionally you can use the `map` RxJS operator to manipulate the results to do things like sort, concat, or whatever else you'd need prior to being emitted by the observable. If you  do NOT need the 1st array, you can simply omit the result selector argument of `switchMap` and just create the final structure/data you'd need/want in `method2()` of this example using `map()`.

While this example shows this being executed in `ngOnInit`, this can be executed at basically moment, for example with a `(click)`. Setting a local property to either `null` or an empty array `[]` can be used with `*ngIf` to conditionally render that data table elements, until the calls have been successfully completed. With an empty array you can check for length greater than zero.

This structure would also allow you to individually result transformation and error handling in each of the calls, keeping things clean and separated.

The example below shows a simple service with HTTP calls emitting `Observables` of various arrays being consumed in a `Component` utilizing `switchMap` to execute the methods/calls in order with `subscribe` obtaining the values from the object created in the `switchMap` result selector using an object destructuring statement. This example uses RxJS 5.5+.

**Service:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';    

Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    method1(): Observable<SomeModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<SomeModel[]>('some/url);
    }

    method2(someInput: SomeModel[]): Observable<SomeOtherModel[]> {            
        return this.http.get<SomeModel[]>('some/url).pipe(
            // you can use the map() operator to do something with the result such as sort, concat, etc before being emitted
            map(result => result.sort())
        );                
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    template: `
        <button (click)="someMethod()" type="button"></button>
        <div *ngIf="data"><!-- data table --></div>
    `
})
export class SomeComponent {
    // null as to be falsy for the *ngIf
    data: SomeModel[] = null;

    constructor(private someService: SomeServie) {}

    someMethod(): void {
        this.someService.method1().pipe(
            switchMap(
                resultArray1 => this.someService.method2(resultArray1),
                (result1, result2) => ({result1, result2}) // you can omit this if you just want to use the 2nd result array
            )
        )
        .subscribe(results => {
            console.log(results);
            const { result1, result2 } = results;                
            // prepare final data in some way you need  
            const data = [...result1, ...result2];                
            this.data = data;
        });

    }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Looks like an exellent answer, will try that... just one additional question:
The code you put into ngOnInit() I would for example put into a method myMethod(). On the HTML side I would place a button, if that button is clicked, myMethod() would be executed. On the same HTML page I would place a DataTable. How to tell the DataTable that the data is available and can be shown in the DataTable? ngIf might be sufficient, but what to place into ngIf, what is the criteria?

Comment: The same code that is in `ngOnInit` can be placed into any method, such as one that's executed from a `(click)` or other event handler. At a very basic level, you can simple assign the local class data array property to null, then use the `ngIf` as you suggested to only display once the calls have been completed and you update the local property with the desired data in the `subscribe`. I'll update the answer to show that at a basic level.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't adopt Staroselsky solution now, as my Angular code is generated by JHipster and most of it is still beyond my knowledge, but I will try as soon as possible.

For now I use a similar solution as Sarker, adding a flag in the second `GET` request in the `subscribe` section ("process data2"), setting the flag to `true` to indicate that data is finally loaded. Still I'm not sure if this solution is the preferred one.

That flag I use in the `*ngIf` of the TurboTable (before it was DataTable).

But I observe a strange behavior, which I posted on [Angular 5 - TurboTable HTML rendering, reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388756/angular-5-turbotable-html-rendering-reload)